# overloading Item on collections

Tags: c#, collections

I have a collection class `MyCollection<T>`.

I have implemented `T this[string name]`, which works fine.

I tried to also implement `T Item(string name)` but of course that gave an error:

> The type `MyCollection<T>` already contains a definition for Item

as it should. However I also want to overload Item by implementing a function `T Item(string, bool)` but this also throws up the same error.

Why would the compiler think that `T Item(string, bool)` clashes with the indexer `T Item(string)`? If it weren't an indexer but just an ordinary method these two declarations would be two perfectly valid overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely overload an indexer - but you can't overload it with a *method* called `Item`. To overload the indexer, you just need:

```
public T this[string name, bool condition]
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, so it looks like:

- You can't have two members of different kinds (one method, one property) with the same name, which is correct according to section 10.3 of the C# 4 spec
- You can't have an indexer *and* a property of name `Item`, which is slightly surprising as they're both properties under the hood

I suspect that you *can* have indexers alongside properties called `Item` if you change the generated name of the indexer's property using [`DefaultMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.defaultmemberattribute.aspx), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: What is intriguing is that why it is impossible to declare one method using Indexer and the one using normal method. After all, after compilation you would have 2 totally different method sigs. And from what I know, IL is even less restrictive in naming, for example it does allow 2 methods to differ only by return type (which is illegal in C#). So, why it's impossible and if it could be done in IL, while it's illegal in C#? I might check the latter one myself.

Comment: @Ravadre: It's not clear whether you're speculating on what the OP did, or on other experience. If this is real experience, it's probably worth asking this as a separate question.

Comment: I am referring to OP post, but what C# actually does not allow to do, is to declare indexer, if you have Item method, any Item method (also, with different signature). Strictly speaking, final OP question: "Why would the compiler think that T Item(string, bool) clashes with the indexer T Item(string)?" Your answer, while perfectly valid (+1) does not answer this question, which I think is quite interesting, and it was asked by OP.

Comment: @Ravadre: I believe it will actually create a `get_Item` method, but an `Item` *property*. The problem is you can't have two members of different kinds (e.g. one method, one property) but the same name. Having said that, I've just failed to introduce a new property called `Item` having added an indexer, too... I would expect that to be valid in IL (where an indexer *is* a property), but apparently it's not valid C#. Checking the spec...

Comment: It seems that might be true, and because OP asked also for _why_ not only _how_, it might be a good idea to promote what you wrote to your post in my humble opinion. Best regards. PS. Checked in Ildasm, and you are right about method and property names created for indexer.

Comment: @Ravadre: I've added a bit more information. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: I had forgotten that you can't actually define a method and a property with the same name, so I guess that's the answer to my question. However, it leaves the question WHY can't you have a method and a property with the same name, especially if the method has paraneters, which a property can never have.

Comment: @Dave: For one thing, it would prevent a method group conversion from working :)